# Using Checkboxes to return a list

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

There is probably either a Tutorial or a dupe I can read in order to figure this out, but I haven't been able to find one by searching on my own. So here is the problem:

I want to create a function `checkboxToList[]` that displays a grid of checkboxes like the following:

```
Column[Table[
  CheckboxBar[ConstantArray[0, alfa + 1], Range[-alfa, 3]]
  , {alfa, 5, 0, -1}
  ]
 , Alignment -> Right
 ]
```

[image]

Then I want the user to be able to make selections, like e.g.

[image]

Finally, by pressing a button or something similar, I want the function to return a list of pairs `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` where the `x` are the row numbers of the checked boxes counting from below, starting from 0, and the `y` are the checkbox labels. Thus, from the second image I would want to return `{{0,0}, {0,1}, {2,-2}, {4,-4}, {4,-2}}`. The order of the pairs in the returned list does not matter to me.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `CheckboxBar[ConstantArray[0, alfa + 1], Range[-alfa, 3]]` is effectively the same as `CheckboxBar[{0}, Range[-alfa, 3]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
checkboxToList[rows_] := DynamicModule[{cbb},
  cbb = ConstantArray[{0}, rows];
  Panel@Column[{
     Column[
      Table[
       With[{pos = alfa + 1}, 
        CheckboxBar[Dynamic[cbb[[pos]]], Range[-alfa, 3]]], {alfa, rows - 1, 
        0, -1}]
      , Alignment -> Right]
     ,
     Button["Checkboxes to List",
      CellPrint@ExpressionCell@Flatten[
         Transpose[{Range[0, Length@cbb - 1], 
            cbb}] /. {{a_, {b__}} :> ({a, #} & /@ {b}), {a_, {}} -> Nothing},
         1]]
     }]
  ]

checkboxToList[6]
```

[image: OutGif]

---

**Edit 1:**

```
SetAttributes[checkboxToList, HoldAll]

checkboxToList[rows_, out_] := 
 DynamicModule[{cbb}, cbb = ConstantArray[{0}, rows];
  Panel@Column[{Column[
      Table[With[{pos = alfa + 1}, 
        CheckboxBar[Dynamic[cbb[[pos]]], Range[-alfa, 3]]], {alfa, rows - 1, 
        0, -1}], Alignment -> Right], 
     Button["Checkboxes to List", 
      out = Flatten[
        Transpose[{Range[0, Length@cbb - 1], 
           cbb}] /. {{a_, {b__}} :> ({a, #} & /@ {b}), {a_, {}} -> Nothing}, 
        1]]}]]

checkboxToList[6, ans]
```

---

**Edit 2:**

```
checkboxToList[rows_] := DynamicModule[{cbb}, cbb = ConstantArray[{0}, rows];
  Panel@Column[{Column[
      Table[With[{pos = alfa + 1}, 
        CheckboxBar[Dynamic[cbb[[pos]]], Range[-alfa, 3]]], {alfa, rows - 1, 
        0, -1}], Alignment -> Right], Button["Checkboxes to List",
      MakeExpression[NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]], StandardForm] /. 
        HoldPattern[{__, out_ = checkboxToList[_]}] :> (out = 
           Flatten[Transpose[{Range[0, Length@cbb - 1], 
               cbb}] /. {{a_, {b__}} :> ({a, #} & /@ {b}), {a_, {}} -> 
               Nothing}, 1]) // ReleaseHold]}]]

ans = checkboxToList[6]
```

Comment: I interpreted "return a list of pairs" as printing it as an `ExpressionCell`, but one can change that to whatever is most appropriate in the context of that function.

Comment: How would you change the `Button` expression so that, if I input `ans = checkboxToList[6]` in the notebook, the variable `ans` would have the list of pairs stored after pressing the button? Is this possible to do?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Please see my edit. Does that work for you too? `ans = checkboxToList[6]` would be possible to, but not necessarily in a way as obvious.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I addet a version that works with `ans = checkboxToList[6]`, but it's kind of an odd way. I'd prefer the version used in **Edit 1**.

Comment: Karsten 7., @andre, thank you both for contributing. My final implementation uses a hybrid of both your answers, so it's hard to chooce what answer to accept. I will accept Karsten 7.'s answer because it also taught me how to use the button in different ways.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that updates the list as soon as you check a box.

```
(* myCheckbox add or remove "elt" to/from the list "choice" *)
SetAttributes[myCheckbox, HoldFirst];
myCheckbox[choice_, elt_] := 
 Checkbox[Dynamic[MemberQ[choice, elt], 
   If[#, AppendTo[choice, elt], choice = DeleteCases[choice, elt]] &]]

choice = {};
Dynamic[choice]

Column[Table[
  Row[Row [{myCheckbox[choice, {alfa, #}], #}, " ", 
      Alignment -> Left] & /@ Range[-alfa, 3], "    "], {alfa, 5, 
   0, -1}], Alignment -> Right]
```

[image]

```
choice
```

> {{4, -4}, {4, -2}, {2, -2}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}

Your approach with `Column[Table[CheckboxBar ...]]` has the drawback that if your checkbox labels have not the same size (vertically), your columns will be missaligned. This problem is solved if you use instead a `Grid[]` of the `myCheckbox[]` above. Example :

```
choice2 = {};
Dynamic[choice2]
Grid[{{Row[{myCheckbox[choice2, "A"], "A"}], 
   Row[{myCheckbox[choice2, "B"], "B"}]}, {, 
   Row[{myCheckbox[choice2, "C"], "CCCCC"}]}}, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]